# Bootstrap scrollspy stoped working when added another scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Hey I'm pretty new with bootstrap and Jquery and started to use a scrollspy with a navbar what works well. And its looks like that:

```
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="65" onload="typeWriter()">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top" style="opacity:0.4;">  
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section4"> Section 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then I just added a scroll activated function and it stopped working so far. I think the multiple scroll function makes the problem but don't know how to deal with that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function getScrollTop(){
        if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
          return pageYOffset;
        }
        else{
          var b = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
          var d = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
          d = (d.clientHeight)? d : b;
          return d.scrollTop;
        }
      }    

      $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        if(getScrollTop() >= 500){
          $(window).off("scroll");

            jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
            },4500);
    });

        };
      });
    </script>
```

There I track the scrolling and when reach the div what I want animate some bars, then deleting the scroll tracker to only animate one time.
So yes after added that function that works well but the navbar stopped tracking where the page at.
I hope there is a solution to that because I also want to use another scroll tracking later for a timeline animation. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes The problem was the two thing uses the same scroll function. I just took out the

```
$(window).off("scroll");
```

and both works now.